# Why is my SerializerBuilder not found in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

I'm trying to use the `JMSSerializerBuilder` to encode my objects in json to be able to make AJAX calls.

I've succesfully installed the bundle through composer.

Then, following [the official documentation](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer), I'm doing:

```
<?php

namespace Pondip\GeolocBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder;   

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function getLakesSurroundingAction($lat=0, $lng=0, $limit = 50, $distance = 50, $unit = 'km')
    {
        $lakesNearby= $this->getNearby($lat, $lng, $limit, $distance, $unit);
        $serializer = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
        $return = $serializer->serialize($return, 'json');
    }

}
```

But it returns

> FatalErrorException:
>
> Error: Class
>   'Pondip\GeolocBundle\Controller\JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder' not
>   found in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\Pondip
>   Dev\src\Pondip\GeolocBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 51

line 51 is:

```
$serializer = JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()->build();
```

Why is that happening?
When removing the `use JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder;` line (since it is not specified in the doc) I just get an internal server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you don't use namespaces correctly. An use statements generates an alias for a specific namespace. The `use JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder;` statement means that `SerializerBuilder` is an alias for the `JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder` class.

When doing `$serializer = JSM\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::create()` in your code, it is an unqualified-namespace, which means it gets into the current namespace. That means PHP is searching for a `Pondip\GeolocBundle\Controller\JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder` (as you're in the `Pondip\GeolocBundle\Controller\` namespace).

To fix this, just use `$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create()`. Because we've set up an alias for the `SerializerBuilder`, it gets to the correct class and everything works.

For more information, please take a look at some "PHP namespacing" tutorials, like [this one](http://phpmaster.com/php-namespaces/).

Comment: Thanksm but now when doing `$serializer = SerializerBuilder::create(); $return = $serializer->serialize($return, 'json');`
I got `FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder::serialize() in C:\Program Files (x86)\wamp\www\Pondip Dev\src\Pondip\GeolocBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 52` which is weird considering it is the main function of this bundle ..

Comment: @MilesM. I recommend to take a look at the docs and just use the `jms_serializer` service: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSSerializerBundle#usage

Answer (score 2):

With `use JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder;` in place you should address the class just as `SerializerBuilder`. Without it, use the fully qualified name `\JMS\Serializer\SerializerBuilder` (notice the leading backslash!)

Further reference: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly had to use `$this->container->get('serializer');` instead of `$serializer = $container->get('jms_serializer');`

Comment: serializer is a component of Symfony not the JMS Serializer itself